# Can two planes intersect in a point?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Is it true that two planes may intersect in a point ?

or

If they intersect then, they always make a straight line ?

I have some doubt; please explain.

Answer (score 20):

In $\Bbb R^3$ two distinct planes either intersect in a line or are parallel, in which case they have empty intersection; they cannot intersect in a single point. In $\Bbb R^n$ for $n>3$, however, two planes can intersect in a point. In $\Bbb R^4$, for instance, let $$P_1=\big\{\langle x,y,0,0\rangle:x,y\in\Bbb R\big\}$$ and $$P_2=\big\{\langle 0,0,x,y\rangle:x,y\in\Bbb R\big\}\;;$$ $P_1$ and $P_2$ are $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$, so they are planes, and their intersection $$P_1\cap P_2=\big\{\langle 0,0,0,0\rangle\big\}$$ consists of a single point, the origin in $\Bbb R^4$. Similar examples can easily be constructed in any $\Bbb R^n$ with $n>3$.

Comment: Seems correct. Still, how do we demonstrate that two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot intersect in a single point.

Comment: @Teddy WLOG remove one zero from P1 and P2. Now there's no way to not get $x=y$, unless they describe the same plane.

Comment: @MarkHurd I think I understand your intention. However, this reasoning only demonstrates that planes of this particular type intersect in a line. What about other planes. What about planes which are not subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (but rather affine spaces) ?

Comment: @Teddy: Simultaneously translate them by the additive inverse of a point of intersection, thereby bringing that point to the origin. Now you’re dealing with subspaces, and their intersection can be translated back to give the intersection of the original planes.

Comment: I might be wrong (have no rigorous proof of what follows), but a curious example that comes to mind would be the (fourth-dimensional) "graph" of the complex identity function **w = f(z) = z**. It seems plausible that the "graph" should be a plane (it has to be a 2D surface immersed in 4D, and I see no reason why it would have any curvature). It is also evident that it should meet the "x axis" (i.e., z-plane, **w = 0**) of this function at **z = 0** only.