# Is it a thereom or an axiom that two planes intersect only in lines?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, 3d

I know that two planes always intersect in a line or are parallel to each other, and there's an question about two planes in a point: [Can two planes intersect in a point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219233/can-two-planes-intersect-in-a-point). But how can you prove that two planes can't intersect in any other shape, like a parabola, a circle, a rectangle or basically any function other than an line? Or is it an axiom that we can't prove?

Comment: It depends on how you set things up.

Comment: Planes are solutions of linear equations.  Any line (which must lie in *both*) must also be linear... hence a line.  QED

Comment: Also, planes are convex sets, so the intersection has to be convex, which eliminates some of the possibilities you've raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments there is a proof by analytic geometry:
Any plane is an solution to a linear equation, as such:
$$ax+by+cz=d$$
$$ex+fy+gz=h$$

Any line which lies in both planes thus must also be linear, so that's why it's a line.

However, I do not think it is possible to prove that in only Euclidean geometry,